# Keeping track of number of times a user has logged in?

Tags: database, cookies, authentication, load

I am implementing a mechanism wherein every user who comes to our site is shown a special splash screen for the first 3 times and then never again.

I could think of the following approaches - what would be the 'best' approach in the sense of reducing overall cost (in terms of server load - both processing speed and database load).

```
A. Having another field in the users table which keeps count
B. Keeping the users which are at different 'states' in different tables 
   (yeah - doesnt make much sense to me either)
C. Keeping count via a cookie at the client end
```

Anything else which is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of server/database load, keeping count in a cookie is easily the best option.  The downside, of course, is that if the user clears or disables their cookies they will see the splash screen again.

Most users do not clear their cookies very often, however, so I'd suggest a hybrid approach.  Use a cookie to keep count, but also add a flag in your database.  As soon as the count in the cookie reaches 3, you set the database flag.  This way, if the user clears their cookies after reaching the required count, you can still remember to not show the splash screen thanks to the flag.

And if the user clears their cookies before reaching the third count, they will still see the splash 3 more times.  But since the user doesn't know how many times the splash should show and since they never reached a state where the splash would stop showing, from their point of view the experience is still consistent.  As soon as they keep the cookie around long enough for the count to reach 3, the splash screens stop, and they stay stopped.

Comment: I'm puzzled why folks are recommending the hybrid approach of having a 'flag in your database' - if I have to conduct a database check every time a user logs-in, i'm creating an equivalent amount of load in the case when I'm keeping count in the database.. @aroth

Comment: @Alan - When the user logs in, aren't you fetching the user's record from the database anyways?  If you are (and I don't see how else a log-in can work) then having the flag (or even the count) in there is really not adding any extra load.  The flag is just slightly more efficient than the count because it gets set only once instead of 3-times (or n-times if you always increment the counter).

Answer (score 0):

Tracking on the clientside (cookie) is the best method, because you don't hit the database and you have no security or reliability concerns.
A slight challenge would be how to detect that the user has started a 'session'. That is, say the user enters page A (which increments the login counter cookie), then goes to page B then goes to A again. You should ensure visit uniqueness; you don't want the counter to increment again. One way to achieve this is by using a second cookie that flags a visit, which its expires value is not set so it expires upon closing the browser etc. .

You can, as a "backup" measure, flag in the database the fact that the user has hit the 3rd time, and then it would be fault tolerant with regards to changing browsers, clearing cookies etc.

Comment: I'm puzzled why folks are recommending the hybrid approach of having a 'flag in your database' - if I have to conduct a database check every time a user logs-in, i'm creating an equivalent amount of load in the case when I'm keeping count in the database.. @Ofer

Comment: 1) Doing a one-time UPDATE command against the database is not like doing 3 hits.

2) I'm not saying the hybrid approach is the best. I explained the client-side attitude, and I was just saying you can back it up with a one-time UPDATE in order to be safe among multiple browsers, cookie deletion etc.

Answer (score 0):

Using a cookie will cause the counter to be reset every time the user changes browser, computer (or mobile device, tablet, etc), empties their cookies, switches to incognito mode,  etc, etc.

Unless you smush the username into the cookie name, it will also count visits from multiple people using the same browser as a single user.

If you want to track this per user, then you need to track it on your server.